# Confused about AngularFire Functions modules and imports

Tags: angularfire2

I spun up a new project with Angular and AngularFire. I ran

```bash
firebase init firestore
firebase init functions
```

This set up this Angular module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions,getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I didn't write any of that. It looks like AngularFire 7.

The [AngularFire Functions documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md) shows a different module setup. It looks like AngularFire 6:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The differences are that the new module has:

```js
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions,getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions())
```

There are two extra lines because I initialized Firestore. The older module has this:

```js
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
...
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
   AngularFireFunctionsModule
```

I left the new module as is and went on to the component. Here's what the AngularFire Functions documentation says to use this (I added a template and stylesheet):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private functions: AngularFireFunctions) { }
}
```

That component throws an error message:

```
R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireFunctions -> InjectionToken
```

It can't inject `AngularFireFunctions`.

I went back to the module and added these lines:

```js
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
...
 imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
```

That doesn't fix the error. The error only goes away when I add this code to the module:

```js
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
```

In other words, I commented out the AngularFire 7 version of `initializeApp` and used the AngularFire 6 version of `initializeApp`.

This code is getting smelly. It seems to me that I should leave the module alone and in the component I should import `httpsCallable` and `AngularFireFunctions` from `@angular/fire/functions`. No problem importing `httpsCallable` but `AngularFireFunctions` isn't on `@angular/fire/functions`.

I feel like the component should look like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Firestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection, updateDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { httpsCallable, AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private functions: AngularFireFunctions) {}
  
  callMe() {
    console.log("Calling...");
    this.functions.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
  }
}
```

The problem is in `AngularFireFunctions`. Has this been replaced with something new in AngularFire 7?

I looked through the AngularFire repo on GitHub looking for `@angular/fire/functions` but I couldn't find this. Where can I see the properties on this type?

Answer (score 0):

There's no AngularFire 7 module for Functions. Use the Firebase module:

```js
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable, httpsCallableFromURL } from "firebase/functions";
```